# KDevelop - force import of cmake project even when selected build directory not empty

Tags: import, cmake, wizard, kdevelop

I've just started using `KDevelop` (ver. 4.6) and I'm having an issue with the way the IDE imports existing `cmake` projects. When you execute `cmake` the pre-selected `build` directory gets filled with all sorts of things including the `CMakeCache`, `make` artifacts, libraries (if defined in the `CMakeLists.txt`), executables etc. This seems to be a problem for `KDevelop` since whenever I try to import a `cmake` project where the `build` directory isn't empty the import is basically impossible since the **OK** button inside the wizard for importing projects is grayed out and it tells me:

```
The selected build directory is not empty
```

Is there a way to force `KDevelop` ignore a full `build` directory during the import process?

Especially when working with `ROS` (Robot Operating System) where a workspace normally has at least a dozen of packages plus downloading additional ones each built at some point having to delete each `build` folder of a package before importing it into `KDevelop` is a tedious work.

**EDIT:** Upgrade to 4.7 or newer version is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked in KDevelop 4.7.3.
- Ran cmake in build folder from terminal.
- Imported project in KDevelop.
The message reads: "Using an already created build directory." and everything works fine.

I also do not have access to a KDevelop 4.6 to check but it might be worth trying 4.7 for you.

Answer (score 0):

KDevelop 4.7 reads the CMakeCache.txt file and checks if it corresponds to the same source directory. I don't remember if it is so for 4.6, so I'd recommend you to upgrade KDevelop.

If it wouldn't help, you'd better [file a bug](https://bugs.kde.org/enter_bug.cgi?format=guided) with instructions to reproduce this.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have administrative privileges (even when building from source you might have to download this and that dev version of a library required for the build process unless you don't want to build ALL dependencies :-/). And upgrade of the Ubuntu distro that I'm running is also not an option. I'll continue looking into this or just dump KDevelop until an upgrade comes for my system.

Comment: Ah, that's the culprit, i guess. KDevelop writes out several files during configuring.